# GetWindowRect seems to be cropping my windows on Win 8.1?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using the following code to get the WindowRect for a process on my machine (been testing with the Windows 8.1 calculator).

```
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rc);

    var bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Right - rc.Left, rc.Bottom - rc.Top, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
    PrintWindow(hWnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
    gfxBmp.Dispose();
```

But on Windows 8.1, the bitmap produced is cropped (in the case of the calculator, by about 100 pixels width and 150 height).

RECT is defined as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
}
```

I've been pulling my hair out with this, can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Rich

Comment: are you running on a high dpi setup, where scaling is something other than 100%?

Comment: Give example values for `rc` members. Is there difference in Windows 7?

Comment: My psychic debugger says that you didn't declare you program to [be dpi-aware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).

Comment: Ignore my last comment. What is **hWnd** and how are you getting it?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, good call on the dpi, I'll check when I'm back at my computer.

Comment: @jp2code hWnd is coming from another MainWindowHandle on the process returned by a GetProcessById call. I assume that works and it is selecting the correct window for the process Id I use, it just crops it. I think the DPI setting might be a good clue so I'll check it out